# Php, Spl, ArrayObject, ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST

Tags: php, spl, arrayobject

I am trying to understand the **[ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)** const,
As it defined at the manual:

**Properties of the object have their normal functionality when accessed as list (var_dump, foreach, etc.).**

I write this code:

```
$array = array(5,7,9,3,6,5,4);
$arrayObj = new ArrayObject($array);
var_dump($arrayObj);
$arrayObj2 = new ArrayObject($arrayObj->getArrayCopy(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);
var_dump($arrayObj2);
```

At the first var_dump we can see the array elements but at the second var_dump you can't see them, I also tested foreach and the foreach loop work for both arrayObj object and arrayObj2 object.

If can some one please explain to me what is normal functionality and why the second var_dump elements is not presented, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: your code works for me. both var_dumps look the same: http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/7x3-dkd

Comment: i can reproduce it, PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10. print_r and count() works but not var_dump

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I am using PHP Version 5.4.3, but lets say its a bug, what doe's the normal functionality as mentioned at the manual definition for STD_PROP_LIST, If some one can explain it to me please.

Answer (score 2):

Am sure you are using anything <= PHP Version 5.3.8 .. It a bug have also detected you would get the following

```
    object(ArrayObject)#1 (7) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(6) [5]=> int(5) [6]=> int(4) } 
    object(ArrayObject)#2 (0) { }
```

If you run on PHP 5.3.10 you would get the following

```
    object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(7) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(6) [5]=> int(5) [6]=> int(4) } } 
    object(ArrayObject)#2 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(7) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(6) [5]=> int(5) [6]=> int(4) } }
```

I think you should upgrade your version of PHP

Comment: the behaviour of flags should only affects the way properties are readable/writable so that's probably a bug.